# Resetting Boostrap Affix with new offset in responsive website

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a website with the following page structure:

[image]

I'm using the Affix plugin so that when the user scrolls past the header, the navigation becomes fixed at the top of the page, like so:

[image]

The website is responsive and when it's in the mobile viewport the header is completely hidden with `display: none`. The problem is I can't seem to get Affix to 'reset' with a new offset, which would now be 0 since the navigation is always at the top of the page in the mobile viewport.

I tried the following:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $("nav").affix({
        offset: $("nav").position()
    });
});
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything. When I resize down to the mobile viewport, the navigation doesn't become fixed until I've scrolled down the page by an amount equal to the size of the header (which is now completely hidden with `display: none`).

I also tried disabling the Affix plugin before re-enabling it:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $(window).off('.affix');

    $("nav").affix({
        offset: $("nav").position()
    });
});
```

But when I resize, the Affix plugin is disabled but doesn't seem to get re-initialised, so even when I resize only a small amount (not all the way down to mobile viewport, so the header is still visible), the navigation doesn't become fixed when I scroll past the header.

I also tried providing offset with a function:

```
function getOffset() {
    return $("nav").position();
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("nav").affix({
        offset: getOffset()
    });
});
```

But the offset value doesn't seem to get updated when I resize to a mobile viewport; the navigation doesn't become fixed until scrolling down the page by an amount equal to the now-hidden header.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it work  for your design if at the mobile viewport you simply used position:fixed; top:0;left:0;width:100%; for the the nav div, and then give the page content div some padding at the top so it clears the nav?